# Prestashop category URL

Tags: php, prestashop

Does anyone know what is the form of PRESTASHOP's category URLs?

What if I want to use other parameters like pagination and number of products to get per request?

For instance, I need to get products under category_id = 33, page = 5, and 10 products per page?

I am hoping there is something similar to the URL of a product.

```
$productUrl = 'http://example.com/index.php?controller=product&id_product=' . $productId;
```

Thank you so much in advanced for any help. It is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic category URL is

```
index.php?controller=category&id_category=<categoryId>
```

In theory the variables `n` and `p` should control the number of products and the page number respectively, but I haven't been able to get them to work very well.

```
index.php?controller=category&id_category=2&n=4&p=2
```

Depending on what you are doing, you may be able to use something like

```
{$link->getCategoryLink({$cat.id_category})}
```

in a template to generate a URL instead.

Comment: John, thank you so much for this. I'm bringing products for display purposes into another site. I'm using ajax for this and your answer is the last part of the puzzle I needed. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

That's worked for me `$this->context->link->getCategoryLink($categoryIdentifier)`